# str_replace and explode function

Tags: php, str-replace, explode

i am writing a code to manipulate a text file that will be open in a browser so far i have is this code:

```
<?PHP

$file_handle = fopen("file.txt", "r") or die("Couldn`t open $file_handle");

while (!feof($file_handle) ) {

$line_of_text = fgets($file_handle);

//$vowels = array("$", "_", "[", "]", "'", ";");
//$var = str_replace($vowels, "", $line_of_text);

$parts = explode('=', $line_of_text);


echo '<table>
      <tr>
      <td>
      <input type="text" size="40" value="'.$parts[0].'">
      <input type="text" size="40" value="'.$parts[1].'">
      </td>
      </tr>
      </table>';
}

fclose($file_handle);

?>
```

i am trying to add  str_replace function i already have explode in my code and do not know how i can have them both in the code so they would work together can anyone give me an example how i can incorporate str_replace in to my code ?

any help will be appreciated :)

Comment: Better use preg_replace

Comment: whats the difference ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To replace `foo` by `bar` in `$parts[0]` for example, use :

```
'<input type="text" size="40" value="'. str_replace('foo', 'bar', $parts[0]) .'">'
```

Refer to the manual of [`str_replace()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php). You'll find more examples there

Answer (score 0):

Maybe like this?

```
$vowels = array("$", "_", "[", "]", "'", ";");
$parts = explode('=', str_replace($vowels, "", $line_of_text));
```